# Is there a Firefox Task Manager?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox

**The previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/71328/task-manager-addon-for-firefox) provides answers for Windows and other addons are for older versions of FF, or do not answer the question.   This is a specific question for OSX.**

Chrome has a built in task manager under "Tools" to look at the process within Chrome, extremely beneficial in locating a stuck page.   What is the similar feature in firefox?

I need to identify what is causing it to run slowly, and the addons they suggested dont work for OSX or are outdated, and Chrome's about:memory isn't recognizing FF

FF Version `17.0`, OSX version `10.8.2 Build 12C3006`

How to get to Task Manager:
[image: where to access task manager]

Task Manager:
[image: task manager for chrome]

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF:**

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Task Manager” addon for Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/71328/task-manager-addon-for-firefox)

Comment: I don't know for sure whether something like this exists or not, but I suspect it may not be possible, due to the way Firefox is architected. Chrome uses a separate process for each tab, which makes it fairly easy to see on a per-tab basis what's using CPU and RAM. Firefox has a single process for the entire browser, which makes getting specific per-tab information much more difficult.

Comment: yes, per tab is likely not possible,  but is there not a way to identify the rogue code/script/addon, similar to the network portion of the debugger?